# Multiple smtp accounts with mutt and msmtp

Tags: mutt, msmtp

I use `mutt` with two different *imap* accounts, and have configured smtp accounts **A** and **B** with `msmtp` and `mutt`.

If I don't specify a default account in `.msmtprc`, `mutt` complains there is no default account when I try to send.

If I set a default account **A**, `mutt` uses this for all imap accounts.

*How can I make it use the smtp account **B** for the corresponding imap account?*

In the account **B** mutt config file I've set the following:

```
## sent
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set use_from=yes
set realname="My Name"
set from=my@gmail.com
set hostname="gmail.com"
set ssl_force_tls=yes
set imap_pass=$my_pass
unset ssl_starttls
```

in .msmtprc the account configuration reads:

```
defaults
tls on
port 587

[...]

account gmail
tls_fingerprint 39:7C:59:20:DE:55:51:F4:8B:72:1D:B5:B2:26:8A:D1:DB:90:C6:28:80:77:F9:B5:EC:C1:BF:1C:6F:4D:A1:63
from my@gmail.com
host smtp.gmail.com
auth on
user my@gmail.com
passwordeval gpg2 --no-tty -q -d ~/mygmail.gpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your mutt configuration for the account (either A or B), you use:

```
set sendmail="/usr/local/bin/msmtp -a [account]
```

which tells msmtp which account parameters to use in .msmtprc.  In my msmtp config,
I specifically set the default to be na which forces the account to be
set in mutt.

Comment: Two things: 1) I think this may need another " and 2) Why does this not work for me at all? It just gives me the error `-a: unknown variable` ???

Comment: @gskapka - if you end the line with closing the quotation as you properly suspect, you shouldn't get the message "unknown variable". I too had a quotation problem, but it was after a send-hook.
`send-hook '~f "@gmail."' 'set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp -a gmail"'`

Answer (score 2):

there's section "Using msmtp with Mutt" within the **EXAMPLES** to the end of `man msmtp`.

> The `envelope_from=yes` option lets Mutt use  the  `-f`  option  of  msmtp. Therefore msmtp chooses the first account that matches the from address you@example.com.

This means in practice: do not specify an account in mutts `set sendmail` path to msmtp. But use some keyboard macro to switch between identities (and from) before sending. For the keyboard marco there are different ways - one of is mentioned in the manual. I'll give you another one and you can choose:

`.muttrc`

```
set sendmail="/usr/bin/msmtp"
set use_from=yes
set envelope_from=yes

alias gmail    Horton Bumblebee <hobumbl@gmail.com>
alias example  H. Bumblebee <hbum@example.com>
macro compose v "<edit-from>^Uidentity\_<tab>" "Select from"
```

`.msmtprc`

```
defaults
 ...

account gmail
  host imap.gmail.com
  from hobumbl@gmail.com
  ...

account example
  host mail.example.com
  from hbum@example.com
  ...
```